# Migrate SVN repo with history over two projects to git

Tags: git, svn, migration, git-svn

We have the problem that we moved several files from one project to another in our svn repo and we want to migrate the new project with full history to git.

SVN looks something like this:

```
|- project-old
   |- branches
   |- tags
   |- trunk (deleted)
       |- file.txt (moved to project new)
|- project-new
   |- branches
   |- tags
   |- trunk
       |- module
          |- file.txt
```

Where we have moved all files from the old project to the new (in sub-folders).

When we only migrate project-new, the history in git starts when the file was moved to project-new and everything is lost before.
Is there a way to preserve to complete history of the files over both (svn) projects?

Comment: clone|fetch from root of repository? and define **by hand** branches|tags specs in `[svn-remote]` section of `.config`? https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html

Comment: This also does not quite work. git log does only show the move, eclipse shows the full commit history, but I can't open old versions or see the annotations.

Comment: I think I can get it to work by clone both separate and then integrate the history of the old project into the new with a series of rebases/cherry picks/squashes. But it will be a lot of work.

Comment: Our Solution:
We are now donig it with exporting the whole svn repo (but filtered)
`git svn clone --trunk=/ --tags=/project-new/tags --branches=/project-new/branches --include-paths='^(project-old/trunk|project-new/trunk)`
With _--include-paths_, only paths within the regex are exported, everything else is ignored.
After that, we delete _project-old_ and move the content of _project-new/trunk_ to the root of the repository.
This way, the history of all files moved between the two projects are preserved.